# HTML table data issue in MFC application

Tags: mfc

I created MFC application based on HTML that using class `CDHtmlDialog` for rendering of HTML, now I want to get table (row, column) data `on_click`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Messaging in `CDHtmlDialog` is handled by [DHTML Event Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/dhtml-event-maps?view=vs-2019).

Insert a hyperlink in html file `<a href="#" id="event_id">text</a>` Handle messages as follows:

```
class CMyDHtmlDialog : public CDHtmlDialog
{
    DECLARE_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()
    HRESULT on_event(IHTMLElement*);
    ...
};

BEGIN_DHTML_EVENT_MAP(CMyDHtmlDialog)
    DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(L"event_id", on_event_id)
END_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()

HRESULT CMyDHtmlDialog::on_event_id(IHTMLElement*)
{
   //MessageBox...
   return S_OK;
}
```