# MFC: how to create dynamic UI via HTML?

Tags: html, visual-c++, mfc

I think this type of questions might have been asked before but I seem not able to find a close match. I want to generate UI dynamically and using HTML might be an easy approach for the job. To start with, I prefer something like below.

```
    CHtmlEditCtrl html_edit_ctrl;
    html_edit_ctrl.SetDocumentHtml("<button>...</button>");
```

I imagine there is some control that allows me to describe the UI based on some dynamic running result. Note that I use CHtmlEditCtrl only as an example, it might be something else which I am not so sure. I don't like to read from a file unless it is much easier or has to be that way.

Then I need to somehow render it in the frame and able to respond to it. For example, suppose I add a button I should be able to capture the button event in the MFC code and respond to that. Eventually I am thinking to render a table of results containing over 1000 rows with each row having interactive elements.

New Edit:

I would like to explore DHTML and here is one thing I need to resolve.

Q: Is it possible to edit event map dynamically?

I imagine I may need something like this.

```
BEGIN_DHTML_EVENT_MAP(CDHTMLDialogDlg)
    DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("event_id_001"), OnButtonOK)
    DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("event_id_002"), OnButtonOK)
    ...
END_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()
```

I can register all button clicked events to one function, which could be fixed. But the number of events cannot be determined until some runtime results show up.

Comment: Doing this in MFC is *way* easier than trying to hook up event handling to an HTML control.

Comment: Try `CDHtmlDialog` with [event handling ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59332526/4603670)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, thank you for the help. Could you please check my new edit?

Comment: You can certainly dynamically chain ActiveX event sinks. Doing so with confidence assumes intimate familiarity with COM, ActiveX, and Connection Points. Lots of simple rules, but you need to know about *all* of them.